# Why is MySQL Workbench telling me I need a semicolon?

Tags: mysql, syntax

This code has passed several online validation tests. I don't know what is wrong. After the `CONCAT` function, it says I need a semicolon, though there already is one there. And on the `end` it says it is extraneous input when it is expecting an end of statement. What gives?

```
create procedure AddColumnUnlessExists(
    IN dbName tinytext,
    IN tableName tinytext,
    IN fieldName tinytext,
    IN fieldDef text)
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE column_name=fieldName
        and table_name=tableName
        and table_schema=dbName
        )
    THEN
        set @ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', dbName, '.', tableName, ' ADD COLUMN ', fieldName, ' ', fieldDef);
        prepare stmt from @ddl;
        execute stmt;
    END IF;
end;
```

Comment: do you use phpMyAdmin to set this stored procedure?

Comment: Nope, I'm working in MySQL Workbench, directly in a query window.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the problem is : you are not using `DELIMITER`.

So just put it this way:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure AddColumnUnlessExists(
    IN dbName tinytext,
    IN tableName tinytext,
    IN fieldName tinytext,
    IN fieldDef text)
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE column_name=fieldName
        and table_name=tableName
        and table_schema=dbName
        )
    THEN
        set @ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', dbName, '.', tableName, ' ADD COLUMN ', fieldName, ' ', fieldDef);
        prepare stmt from @ddl;
        execute stmt;
    END IF;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql
>   itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must
>   redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire
>   stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

Comment: I'm not quite clear as to what exactly this changed, but this got things to work.  But I had to delete the last `DELIMITER`.  It was giving `extraneous input found`

Comment: yes you have a reason, you should add semicolon there. check my update.

Comment: Extra space between last DELIMITER  and semicolon worked for me. DELIMITER ;

Comment: the same problem as in the command line since the `;` in the procedure body conflicts with the final end `;`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the delimiter, you should change the delimiter. I hadthe same problem and changing the delimiter solved the issue. 
Refer to @Alex Answer.

Here is an simple explanation, quoting MySQL documentation:

> The example uses the mysql client delimiter command to change the
>   statement delimiter from ; to // while the procedure is being defined.
>   **This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed
>   through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.
>   See Section 22.1, “Defining Stored Programs”.**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

```
DELIMITER // 
create procedure some_procedure() 
# Do what you need here

END // 

DELIMITER ; # change the delimiter back again.
```